# Google Play Billing: identifying duplicate transactions

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there any way to see if an in-app transaction concerns with an item already owned by a user? Our reports get a bunch of duplicate transactions due to people re-purchasing stuff (after removing the app or switching user accounts) – they don't get charged on Google side for purchasing the unconsumed items multiple times and we need a way to know that.

We tried the following ways:

1. `OrderId` field from purchase receipt – seems to be unique every time,
   even if the item is already owned.
2. `PurchaseToken` – despite having a
   number of formats, it seems to be the same for transactions that
   involve purchasing the same item by the same person, **however** a
   few of our users still get unique purchase tokens every time they
   "purchase".

Is there any way to tell if in-app purchase of this product has already happened in the past (like referring to `transaction_id` field from original iTunes receipt in Apple ecosystem)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to tell if in-app purchase of this product has
>   already happened in the past?

AFAIK the In-app billing API doesn't provide such info for consumed products (I assume you use products and not subscriptions).

The cases are:

1. For non consumed products you should get `RESPONSE_CODE` with value 7 - `ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` from the `getBuyIntent` method, so you might just not consume the products on the client side and just keep them indefinitely.
2. For consumed products you might want to save the product SKU (`productId`) on your app, or associate it with some kind of user account if your system uses user sessions. That way, with the next attempt to buy the product you can match the SKU and just programatically disallow the app to start the intent sender for buying a specified SKU product.

Both `orderId` and `purchaseToken` should be unique for a given transaction. They are for further use, for example with the [Google Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html), ie: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get (see `token` in request params).

- Alternatively you might use the said developer API and optional `developerPayload` field (however you wish to do that) to match users of your system and play store transactions.